# bootstrap navbar with margin both side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to customize my navbar (bootstrap) with margin both sides.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
                 <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COMPANY</a>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar{
left:100px;
right:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. add css style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;"  to the div navbar see below code.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
```

COMPANY

Home

Comment: use your desired pixel

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar.navbar-static-top {
    margin:0 auto; /*center the element*/
    width: 80% !important;/* customize width you want */
}

.navbar.navbar-static-top .container /*overwrite bootstrap style*/
{
width:100%!important;
 }
```

**OR TRY THIS CODE**
!important tag when its needed in your page

```css
.navbar-static-top
{
width:80%;
margin:0 auto;
}
.navbar-static-top .container
{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COMPANY</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: describe your answer some more. read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try do that in CSS:

```
.navbar {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

Comment: when adjusting in mobile phones the output is superslim page

Answer (score 0):

```
    .navbar
    {
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:100px;
    }
```

Comment: when adjusting in mobile phones the output is superslim page

Comment: How also to align with the same container in second page?

Answer (score 0):

To also cater for mobile responsiveness, try this CSS:

```
.navbar {
    display: inline-block;  /*to make sure .navbar accepts width*/
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about your question. Are you asking to give blank spaces between navigation bar and html body? or you need blank spaces within your navigation menu? 
If you need blank space between menu and html body just do the following things

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COMPANY</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Just check with this add or delete the col to increase or decrease width of your navigation bar..

OR

Just simply add your coding within container so that you  can get spaces in either direction